# How can I tell if a user has left my website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, packet

Is there a way to tell if a user on my website has left (i.e. connection dropped, navigated away etc.) in real time?

I am building a RoR website and want to initiate an event as soon as a user leaves my site for whatever reason (e.g. connection, navigating away from domain etc.)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What if the user walks away from his computer?

Comment: @SLaks: JavaScript, settimeout for like five or ten minutes on a page and then use AJAX to get the information back to the server. (Edit: Naturally this won't account for just the user staying on the same page that long. But I'm just showing that there IS a possibility!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't.

The best you can do is send an AJAX request every X seconds (perhaps only if the user moves the mouse).  If the server doesn't receive any requests for 2X seconds, assume that the user left.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

Http = [connectionless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectionless_protocol)

Answer (score 2):

You can do some request in this function:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){ 
  // there
});
```

Send some Ajax or something to tell the server that this user is leaving the page, but this is not a good idea. In Google analytics and in other statistic services you already can see how long the user stays in your page.

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of is JavaScript `onunload` event in your body  tag... I don't know how viable that is, but in theory you could have that use an AJAX call to send information about an impending disconnect.

Of course, if the browser process is just killed that won't work.

And I'm not sure if Rails has any unique magic that does this same thing (except better).

Comment: @SLaks: True. I guess your approach of proactively sending heartbeat info is better.